Margin between textbox and label
in addition to the previous question, I want to change the background colour of the checkbox to orange when the user checks on it.
I also want the user to be able to click on the checkbox by clicking on the text next to the checkbox. pls help.
I want to have a gap between a checkbox and a span. I wrap a checkbox and a span in the label element.
I tried all possible ways to add a gap between the two elements but it didn't work, please help.


/*.options {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.options label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #777;

}

.options .input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 1px; 
*/
<div class="options">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Keep me logged in</span>
  </label>
  <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
</div>




I converted your code to a running snippet, but I didn't edit or modify that code (other than formatting it), so I just want to ask why you've wrapped your CSS in comments, which prevents them from working?

If you add display: inline-block to the <span> margins should work as you expected.



<form>
  <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" style="margin-left: 1rem">
    </label>
</form>



1.The for attribute of  must be equal to the id attribute of the
related element to bind them together.
This one you can refer to @Vipul's answer
2.A label can also be bound to an element by placing the element inside
the  element.
<form>
    <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text" name="username" style="margin-left: 1rem">
    </label>
  </form>


This is not the correct way of using the label tag.
you could just go with
 <input type="checkbox" id="input1"> <label for="input1" class="label1">Keep me logged in</label>
The for attribute can be used to associate a label with an input
you can wrap both inside div element if you have multiple and just put spacing using class added to label and margin css.


.options {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.options div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #777;

}

.options label {
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
<div class="options">
  <div>
    <label for="cb1">Keep me logged in</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
  </div>
  <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
</div>



Hope this helps!.



/*.options {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.options label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #777;

}

.options .input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 1px; 
*/
<div class="options">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Keep me logged in</span>
  </label>
  <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
</div>




Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can add gap between elements by using gap: 10pxwith display: flex. Add this properties to <label> and you are all set.


label{
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
<div class="options">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Keep me logged in</span>
  </label>
  <a href="#">Reset Password</a>
</div>



Thank You.

The solution worked. I want to change the background of the checkbox to orange when it's clicked. I also want both the checkbox and the text to be a link so the user can select the checkbox by clicking the text or the checkbox. I tried to wrap them in a tag but didnt work

@AbdullahiAhmed currently they are linked already, you can check - uncheck box by clicking text.
